# Windows 10 boots to a black screen from GRUB in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After installing Ubuntu Budgie on my gaming PC, I have encountered a few boot problems. When my PC boots up, it first takes me to the GRUB command line where I have to type 'exit' to enter the GRUB menu. Secondly, when I choose Windows 10 from the GRUB menu, the Windows logo comes up, it seems to boot, but then nothing, just a black screen.

(Would using command prompt and bootrec commands from Windows install disk fix this?)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Or is Windows UEFI and Ubuntu BIOS as that can cause issues. You always should be able to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu.  Also is Windows fast start up still on. (Windows on updates may also turn it back on, and you need it off for grub to boot Windows).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If still issues post link to summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an Ubuntu emergency disk and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.